How to instantiate a service reference (svc) in .NET 6
I added a service reference to my .NET 6 project. And then I created this factory (simplified):
public class InfoServiceClientFactory
{
    public IInfoService Create(string url)
    {
          BasicHttpBinding x = ClientExtensions.GetBinding();
          EndpointAddressy = url.GetEndpointAddress();
          return new InfoServiceClient(x, y);
    }
}

When I compile this code, I get this error at the line
new InfoServiceReference(..)


Error CS7069:
Reference to type 'IBindingRuntimePreferences' claims it is defined in 'System.ServiceModel.Primitives', but it could not be found

This is the only error found.
Seems like IBindingRuntimePreferences isn't part of .NET 6, so how do I prevent my project from needing it?
(The service reference was a .svc service reference).
